# Генерация карты

Tags: html5, canvas, разработка-игр

Пишу html5 canvas игру, не могу разобраться как выполняется генерация таких карт. Все карты разного размера и масштаба. Обьясните чайнику хотя бы в двух словах как это работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: карты не такие, но информация может быть полезна - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCmjnqoXfHc , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIBgWhJTBX4